# Properly controlling texture mapping

Tags: uv, texture-coordinates

I'm sure an unbelievably dumb question; I think I just don't know the correct search term...

[image]I've applied a simple square checker pattern to an object.

How do I prevent the checker pattern from distorting; at present it stretches according to the proportions of the surfaces, when it should be uniform all over?

Answer (score 2):

First thing, you have a scale of 0.4/1/0.45, so apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. If it is still distorted, as you are using the UV output of the *Texture Coordinate*, select your whole mesh in *Edit* mode and take a look into your *UV Editor*, your UVs are probably not proportional and you need to redo it properly.

Comment: Thanks - that's a great improvement, although I still don't feel like I'm even remotely in control of this thing!

Comment: did it fix your problem? If not, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/